# How to use function return value as a state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-state

I am learning functional components with React and I have a simple code, which returns 'Nah' when the state value is 0.

The problem is that this doesn't work during render. Why is that?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const formatCount = () => {
    count === 0 ? setCount("Nah") : setCount(0);
  };

  // let classes = "badge m-2";
  // classes += (this.state.count === 0) ? "badge-warning" : "badge-primary";

  return (
    <div>
      <Button className="badge badge-warning m-2">-</Button>
      {this.formatCount()}
      <button>+</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

Comment: i am also new to react but anyway. your `count` is initially 0. now if you render your html tags ( well witch are actually JSX) you execute your function because of the parenthesis at the end `()`. your function checks now if count is `0` and it is true. now `setCount()` changes your count variable to `nah`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a couple of things in your code that could be done differently.

First of, your function `formatCount()` doesn't return a value. So there's pretty much nothing to show when executing it.

Second, your function is executed before the state updates the value, causing it to always stay `0`.

A better way to do this would be:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
      formatCount();
  }, []);

  const formatCount = () => {
    count === 0 ? setCount("Nah") : setCount(0);
  };

  // let classes = "badge m-2";
  // classes += (this.state.count === 0) ? "badge-warning" : "badge-primary";

  return (
    <div>
      <Button className="badge badge-warning m-2">-</Button>
      {count}
      <button>+</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

This causes the `count` to be updated at render and automatically re-rendered to the screen on change.

More info about the `useEffect()` hook can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for your help! but why the formatCount does not return value...?? I thought arrow function returns value with out return.... isnt it?

Comment: @jenny That's true, but the `setCount()` doesn't return a value. The only way to retrieve the value would be to return `count` or use it in the JSX render

Comment: @jenny Keep in mind that arrow function only returns the value if you don't open brackets, if you do open the brackets arrow function does not return without explicitly calling return.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should deal with numbers not strings.

Comment: Noo.. because I changed the state as '0', it also not working..

Answer (score 0):

Problems,

#### 1:

```
{this.formatCount()}
```

You are in functional component not class, So no need of `this`

#### 2: (main)

```
count === 0 ? setCount("Nah") : setCount(0);
```

It Has recursion, 
First `count` is `0` which triggers `setCount("Nah")`  
Then, in the second render, `count` is not `0` which triggers `setCount(0)`

And this loop breaks the app

### FIX

use something like this,

```
const formatCount = () => {
    return count === 0 ? 'Nah' : count
}
```

Comment: and what does `useEffect` do? i thought its used to track if some variable made any changes to execute an function depending on it

Comment: @jenny added that checkout now

Comment: @Ifaruki  WHAAAT !! where did you find  `useEffect` in the question ??

Comment: @aXuser264 its not in the question i just asking it.